# How to measure execution time of ASA job on edge device and on cloud?

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-cloud-services, azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-edge

I am running azure stream analytics query on edge device as well as on cloud.
I have watermark delay seconds for both stream analytics pipelines.
But How can I measure execution time of azure stream analytics jobs on edge as well as on cloud?

Thanks.

Comment: Check out this post about understanding time in ASA: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-time-handling Also, there is a similar ask in Q&A : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/742112/how-to-measure-execution-time-of-azure-stream-anal.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as an execution time for a job. A job can have multiple queries, that each output events at different times. Some will take a message and output a message. The other will take 100 messages and output 1. And again others will do compute over a time window and output events whenever the window ends.

The job itself can be started and stopped, but I don't think the time between those two actions is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, basically I am firing same ASA query on cloud and edge, based on tumbling window to filter the data, and I want to see the time to execute query. Every 1 second interval it receives stream of almost 60 data elements average. Within what time it process 60 elements?